# Prices in Magento are rounding up instead of down

Tags: tax, vat, rounding

We have a Magento store where the prices entered by admin are excluding VAT. VAT is added at a rate of 20% and should display on the product page, basket and checkout but for some crazy reason some VAT inclusive prices are always rounding up when they should be rounding to the nearest penny/cent.

Eg:

> Price in Magento
>   41.31
>
> Correct calculation of price
>   41.31 * 1.2 = 49.572
>
> What Magento should display
>   49.57
>
> What Magento actually displays
>   49.58

How can I fix Magento so it displays 49.57?

Answer (score -1):

**Open  code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php**

**on line no 194**

```
 public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
        {
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
        }
```

**change this code to:-**

```
public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
    {
return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
    }
```

**After Changing This:-**

> Clear the Cache.
>
> Go to System –> Cache Management  Refreh Cache.
>
> If you have not enabled the Cache OR if it didn’t work even after
>   refreshing the cache, then  delete the cache folder present inside var (var/cache)

Comment: Please do not just edit the core file, you'll loose those changes when you update your shop later. Better create a rewrite for the specific file and just overwrite that one method.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem anyway, your suggested change would make `49.572` display as `50` or `42.22` as just `42` (for example). It just changes the decimal formatting and is nothing to do with the rounding...